# How can I listen timeupdate event while recording?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, video.js, video-recording

Is it possible to listen timeupdate event and get current time while recording?
I using videojs with videojs-record plugin to record video and audio.
I tried listen timeupdate on player object of videojs but was no result - it's not triggered

Comment: Attach `timeupdate` event to `<video>` element.

Comment: @guest271314 as attribute? or what did you mean? Can you give any example
Thanks in advance

Comment: @guest271314 could you help me please?

Comment: Have not tried videojs. Can you include what you have tried at Question?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://collab-project.github.io/videojs-record/#/recorded-data?id=timestamps

Basically enable the event with the `timeSlice` option:

```
record: {
    audio: false,
    video: true,
    maxLength: 5,
    debug: true,
    // fire the timestamp event every 2 seconds
    timeSlice: 2000
}
```

And listen for the timestamp event. For example:

```js
// monitor stream data during recording
player.on('timestamp', function() {
    // timestamps
    console.log('current timestamp: ', player.currentTimestamp);
    console.log('all timestamps: ', player.allTimestamps);

    // stream data
    console.log('array of blobs: ', player.recordedData);
    // or construct a single blob:
    // var blob = new Blob(blobs, {
    //     type: 'video/webm'
    // });
});
```